# Put a current date in a footer (FPDF)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Everything is written in the title.

I did not find any resource showing how to do it.
I create a PDF document with FPDF for a PHP site. I added the page number in the footer but I can't add the current date in the format: "Monday 18 April 2022".

*See the code :*

class PDF extends FPDF {
function Header() {}

```
function Footer() {
    // Positionnement à 1,5 cm du bas
    $this->SetY(-15);

    // Police Arial italique 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Numéro de page
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().' sur {nb}',0,0,'R');
}
}
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4');
```

I can't enter php code in the Footer() class, and i can't even put php variables prepared beforehand.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Are you asking how to output a date in that specific format, or how to include such a thing in your footer, or what? Since you said you already included the page number, it seems you've got the basic idea about including data in the footer, so you need to be more specific about what you want help with. "Can't" isn't a clear question or problem description. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another call to `$this->Cell()` will allow you to insert a date to your footer. The third argument will be the date string which you can generate with PHP using the inbuilt `date()` function or date objects. The parameters for the `Cell` method are explained in the FPDF docs at http://www.fpdf.org/ under `manual`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the end I found it!

Here is the code :

```
function Footer() {
        // Positionnement à 1,5 cm du bas
        $this->SetY(-15);

        // Police Arial italique 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);

        // Date du jour
        setlocale(LC_TIME, "");
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
        $date_du_jour = utf8_encode(strftime('%A %d %B %Y'));
        $this->Cell(0,10,$date_du_jour,0,0,'L');
        
        // Numéro de page
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().' sur {nb}',0,0,'R');
    }
```